# Laravel 5.6 - Can't pass variable to email view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have setup a mailer in a Laravel 5.6 app but am struggling to pass variables to the view, my welcome.php controller looks like this..

```
namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class Welcome extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $user;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.welcome');
    }
}
```

Any my view looks like this..

```
Your registered email-id is {{$user->email}}
```

I am calling the email controller after a user is created like this...

```
$user->save();
Mail::to($user->email)->send(new Welcome($user));
```

I am getting an error message telling me that **undefined variable: user**

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit tour mail file

```
public function __construct($user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}

public function build()
{
    return $this->view('emails.welcome')->with(['user' => $this->user]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 3):

Your constructor is not accepting any variable...

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->user = $user;
}
```

Change it to:

```
public function __construct($user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}
```

Or you can type hint it like this:

```
use App\User;


...


public function __construct(User $user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}
```